# On which Thread JxBrowser execute click DOM element

Tags: java, dom, jxbrowser

Here we have a simple `DOMElement`

```
DOMElement button = document.findElement(By.id("action_button");
```

... and when I execute click on them as

```
button.click();
```

And I have a question: Did API will execute click on the same Thread ? Or  will be created other Thread which execute this `.click()` ?

I ask about it because I search best way (the fastest way) to execute click at DOM elements by browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you invoke the click() method it adds the click message into the message queue which is processed in the separate thread asynchronously by message sender.